How to use Message Application Command (context menu command) in private dms. Pycord/discord.py
@commands.message_command(
        name="Remind Me"
    )
    async def message_com(self, ctx, message):
        view = util.reminderInteraction.ReminderSelectView(
            self.process_reminder,
            ctx=ctx,
            message_content=message.content,
            message_by=message.author.global_name,
        )
        await ctx.respond(view=view, ephemeral=True)

This only shows up in guilds and the bots dm, I want to be able to use this command in my dm's with other users as well.
I have seen some contexts and integration type in official discord api docs, maybe its something with that, but pycord doesn't that.

Ok so first things first, your indentation is wack (but at least you're using a code block. Second, this is not implemented into Pycord yet. However, it's in the master branch of the repo. Four days ago, the user installable apps were comitted. See if that works by git cloning the repo and using that instead. This also means that it won't be in the docs yet because although it's technically implemented it's not in the main library yet.

My previous comment is outdated and the newest answer provides the way to do that (it's implemented now )

This feature has now been released with py-cord 2.6. You can install it with pip install py-cord==2.6.
Here is an example code, taken from the official examples:
import discord

# debug_guilds must not be set if we want to set contexts and integration_types on commands
bot = discord.Bot()


@bot.slash_command(
    # Can only be used in private messages
    contexts={discord.InteractionContextType.private_channel},
    # Can only be used if the bot is installed to your user account,
    # if left blank it can only be used when added to guilds
    integration_types={discord.IntegrationType.user_install},
)
async def greet(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.respond(f"Hello, {user}!")


@bot.slash_command(
    # This command can be used by guild members, but also by users anywhere if they install it
    integration_types={
        discord.IntegrationType.guild_install,
        discord.IntegrationType.user_install,
    },
)
async def say_hello(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.respond("Hello!")


# If a bot is not installed to a guild and the channel has the `USE_EXTERNAL_APPS`
# permission disabled, the response will always be ephemeral.


bot.run("TOKEN")

